# When I use the same seed phrase for both Ethereum and RSK, why is my address capitalised differently?

Tags: ethereum, checksum, seed, rsk

If I import the same private key in ETH and RSK networks, the account is the same but the capitalization is different. Why is this? Is this OK?

Answer (score 6):

Capitalization is used as a checksum, and the following standards are involved

- [SLIP-0044](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md)
- [EIP-155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md#user-content-list-of-chain-ids)
- [EIP-1191](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1191.md)

Some wallet software allow you to configure the chain ID/ network ID, and others do not

- In wallets that **leave out** the chain ID, the capitalization based checksum will be the same in RSK as that of Ethereum. Example: MetaMask
- In wallets that **include** the chain ID, the capitalization based checksum will be different in RSK compared to Ethereum. Example: Nifty Wallet.

In both cases, a workaround is possible, and specified in EIP-155:
Use all lower case to skip checksum checks

Answer (score 4):

This question maybe is not ONLY about checksum, because the same seed phrase for both Ethereum and RSK have different derivation paths by default.

- RSK Mainnet derivation path: m/44’/137’/0’/0 RSK
- Testnet derivation path: m/44’/37310’/0’/0
- Ethereum derivation path: m/44'/60'/0'/0'/0 (for all networks: Mainnet, Ropsten, Rinkeby, Goerli, etc)

https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/architecture/account-based/

Comment: Yes, that is right, the derivation path **does not** affect the checksum calculations. It is only the `chainId` plus whether EIP-1191 or EIP-155 is used that **does** affect the checksum calculations.

Answer (score 0):

[Ethereum encodes address checksum in the capitalisation of hexadecimal letters of the address](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md).

It might be that whatever RSK tool you are using is not supporting this convention. In this case, you can convert non-checksummed address to checksummed, capitalised format, yourself.